# Why is my following matrix statement failing

Tags: r, matrix

```
matrix_1 = matrix(rep(c("p","r"),6), c(rep("control",6), rep("concussion",6)),
                  nrow = 12, ncol = 2)
```

It says invalid byrow argument (I want it by column and byrow is F by default) so I basically want the first column to have p and r repeated 6 times for a total of 12 rows and the second column to have Control in first 6 rows and Concussion in the next 6

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `matrix` is

> matrix(data = NA, nrow = 1, ncol = 1, byrow = FALSE,
>          dimnames = NULL)

So, if the `data` is being split up like in the OP's post, one of the arguments that is not specified would be incorrectly being labelled as `byrow`i.e. in the OP's code,

```
 data = rep(c("p","r"),6)
```

The `nrow` and `ncol` arguments are specified, leaving the other two arguments in the order to take up the rest of the input i.e.

```
c(rep("control",6), rep("concussion",6))
```

would be mistakenly taken as argument for `byrow`.  However, `byrow` takes a logical argument and it is a potential reason for the error.

```
matrix_1 = matrix(rep(c("p","r"),6), c(rep("control",6), rep("concussion",6)),
                 nrow = 12, ncol = 2)
```

> Error in matrix(rep(c("p", "r"), 6), c(rep("control", 6),
>   rep("concussion",  :    invalid 'byrow' argument

If we specify the `byrow = FALSE`, then the error will be based on the `dimnames`

```
matrix_1 = matrix(rep(c("p","r"),6), c(rep("control",6), rep("concussion",6)),
                  nrow = 12, ncol = 2, byrow = FALSE)
```

> Error in matrix(rep(c("p", "r"), 6), c(rep("control", 6),
>   rep("concussion",  :    'dimnames' must be a list

---

As there is only a single `data` argument, we need to concatenate the strings

```
matrix_1 <-  matrix(data = c(rep(c("p","r"),6),c(rep("control",6),rep("concussion",6))),
     nrow=12,ncol=2)
```

Now, as `byrow = FALSE` by default it will not get affected